# Prevent file to get write from user or any application

Tags: java

I have an application that loads cofiguration from a file which reside in a particular location. I found some problem while loading information from file when user or any one disrupts it so how can i prevent user to modify it. If i made it readonly then it would be tedious for my application to update it.
so please give some quick inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a lock in a file?

http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/locking-files-using-java/

> File locking is a mechanism that restricts access to a computer file by allowing only one user or process access at any specific time. Systems implement locking to prevent the classic interceding update scenario (see race condition). (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking)

With a lock, what you will achieve, is granting a block on a file, and only the user / process that locked it, will be able to perform tasks on it, while the rest, will be notified that they're unable to edit it as it's locked by someone else.

Edit:

To check if the file has been modified since your last changes by Java Application, what you could do is create a MD5 Hash, when you're done editing it. Then save it somewhere. And everytime you try to edit that file, you can just check if it has been modified by comparing the actual md5 hash with the one you've stored last time.

Comment: @Thihara I was on it.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán  this is kind of lock that acquire to access it but i want how to validate, that file is not going to be modified i want it remain same as my application update it.

Comment: Can you please explain yourself better? If a user is an admin or a root user, he will be able to modify / edit that file. There's nothing unbreakable. However, if you're looking to validate, what I'd do is something clean. Once finished editing file with java, create a md5 hash. And every time you try to open that file again, check the hash. If it's the same as the one you've left behind, the file is not modified.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán that i also think for validation purpose if we could not stop user to modify it then how can i get my last written content means versioning it would become tedious i think so is there any possility that i can stop user to stop to modify it by any check.

Comment: If user wants to modify it, he will surely be able to modify it. Period. All you can do is do validations on hash. You can also save the "original" last correct file, and in case hash is different, you could restore the file with that original one. But obviously this means you've to version it.